# pretty photo not working on dynamically created <a> tags

Tags: prettyphoto

I created a link using

```
<a href="somepage.php?iframe=true&amp;width=550&amp;height=350" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]">add details</a>
```

This link works fine and it opens the page as a popup. But there are some link which are dynamically created on the page in the same way. When I click on these links, they open up on the browser directly rather than as a pop. How to make them open as a popup? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the html the dynamically created page generates?

Comment: @morgan yes the dynamically created html is perfect and is same as one in the question..

Answer (score 0):

With some hit and trial, I was able to make it working. Its just that we need to initialize prettyphoto again after adding the  tag.